# My default gulp task is not executing other tasks

Tags: gulp

I've got a gulp task that works when I run task at a time but for some reason I don't get, when I run the "default" task, all that runs is clean.  Any ideas what i've got wrong?  Script below.

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

        // Load plugins
        var gulp = require('gulp'),
            uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
            rename = require('gulp-rename'),
            concat = require('gulp-concat'),
            notify = require('gulp-notify'),
            htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

        gulp.task('scripts', function () {
            return gulp.src(['public/app/**/*.js','public/app.js'])
                .pipe(concat('main.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
                .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
                .pipe(notify({message: 'Scripts task complete'}));
        });


        gulp.task('copyfiles', function () {
            gulp.src('public/dist/**/*')
                .pipe(gulp.dest('../../ExtJSApps/dash1'))
                .pipe(notify({message: 'copyfiles task complete'}));
        });

        gulp.task('indexhtml', function () {
            gulp.src('public/index.html')
                .pipe(rename('indexnomin.html'))
                .pipe(htmlreplace({
                    'css': '/ExtJSApps/ext-4.2.2.1144/resources/ext-theme-neptuneext-theme-neptune-all-debug.css',
                    'js': ['/ExtJSApps/ext-4.2.2.1144/ext-all-dev.js',
                        'main.js']
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/'))
                .pipe(notify({message: 'indexhtml task complete'}));
            //console.log('2x');
        });

        gulp.task('indexhtmlmin', function () {
            gulp.src('public/index.html')
                .pipe(htmlreplace({
                    'css': '/ExtJSApps/ext-4.2.2.1144/resources/ext-theme-neptune/ext-theme-neptune-all.css',
                    'js': [
                        '/ExtJSApps/ext-4.2.2.1144/ext-all.js',
                        'main.min.js'
                    ]
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/'))
                .pipe(notify({message: 'indexhtmlmin task complete'}));
        });

        gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
        });

        // Default task
        gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
            gulp.start('scripts','copyfiles', 'indexhtml', 'indexhtmlmin');
        });
    }());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('scripts','copyfiles', 'indexhtml', 'indexhtmlmin');
});
```

to

```
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'scripts', 'copyfiles', 'indexhtml', 'indexhtmlmin']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Last line wrong parenthesis:

`}());`

should be

`})();`

Also you should know that `gulp.start` is [deprecated](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/505) and you should look into [gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins) and general [gulp architecture](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/small-sips-of-gulp-dot-js-4-steps-to-reduce-complexity).

Comment: Hi @ninive, I'm not sure how I'm using gulp.start and what I should be using instead?  Also, my copyfiles runs 5x everytime I run it. any idea why?  thanks for js correction also.